# Getting GeoServer to batch delete features using WFS

Tags: geoserver, features, wfs-t, delete

I'm having some problems using Geoserver to batch delete features, It looks like the Geoserver does not respond properly when the number of deleted features is greater than 30. 
The format of the request I send is as follows:

```
    <Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Delete typeName="feature:public.facilities" xmlns:feature="http://geoserver/postgres">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <FeatureId fid="public.facilities.ec8eb9fa-e25d-48ff-a2c7-ff9d40361885"/>
    </Filter>
  </Delete>
  <Delete typeName="feature:public.facilities" xmlns:feature="http://geoserver/postgres">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <FeatureId fid="public.facilities.f9767af1-4fe2-42cf-8ca6-6e8ea094b99a"/>
    </Filter>
  </Delete>
  <Delete typeName="feature:public.facilities" xmlns:feature="http://geoserver/postgres">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <FeatureId fid="public.facilities.ffc2d135-b1af-4c59-a89f-9c745170e893"/>
    </Filter>
  </Delete>
  ... ...
</Transaction>
```

1、When I delete 10 features, it will be done correctly in 60 ms.
2、When I delete 20 features, it will be done correctly in 1.7s.
3、When I delete 30 features, it will be timeout after 1min.
It looks like the delete operation time increases dramatically with the number of deletes.When the number of deleted features reaches 30, the response times out. As a result, the deletion operation cannot be performed correctly.
So my question is, how to batch delete features in a single transaction?
Geoserver: 2.20.4
Postgres: 11
I've turned on prepared statements and increased Batch insert size, as [Geoserver WFS-T performance degraded after upgrading to 2.20](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431308/geoserver-wfs-t-performance-degraded-after-upgrading-to-2-20)
But it didn't solve my problem. Insert and Update has no problems. Only Delete has the timeout problem.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what happens on the database side when Geoserver is timing out? Do some of the records get deleted? Also can you manually delete those same 30 records directly from the database? (might be DB problem?)

Comment: Looks the same as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431308/geoserver-wfs-t-performance-degraded-after-upgrading-to-2-20 .  Same answer, please open a ticket with a fully reproducible test case.

Comment: Thanks. I've turned on prepared statements. Insert and Update has no problems. Only Delete has the timeout problem.